# Creating an Apex Class for a default email template

Tags: apex, email, email-template, class

I'm looking for a simpler method with which to set a default email template without having to use Case Status or Case Reason. Instead, I'd like to use just the Case Record Type.

```
global class SmartTemplateLoader implements Support.EmailTemplateSelector {
    // Empty constructor
    global SmartTemplateLoader() {}
    // The main interface method
    global ID getDefaultEmailTemplateId(ID caseId) {
        // Select the case we're interested in, choosing any fields that are relevant to our decision
        Case c = [SELECT Status, Reason FROM Case WHERE Id=:caseId];

        Smart_Template_Loader_Conf__c conf = null;
        List<Smart_Template_Loader_Conf__c> confs = null;

        // get template from case status + case reason
        confs = [SELECT Template_Name__c FROM Smart_Template_Loader_Conf__c WHERE Case_Status__c = :c.status and Case_Reason__c = :c.reason];
        if (!confs.isEmpty()) {
            conf = confs[0];
            System.debug('got template: ' + conf.Template_Name__c);
        }

        // get template from case status
        if (conf==null) {
            confs = [SELECT Template_Name__c FROM Smart_Template_Loader_Conf__c WHERE Case_Status__c = :c.status];
            if (!confs.isEmpty()) {
                conf = confs[0];
                System.debug('got template: ' + conf.Template_Name__c);
            }
        }
        // get template from case reason
        confs = [SELECT Template_Name__c FROM Smart_Template_Loader_Conf__c WHERE Case_Reason__c = :c.reason];
        System.debug('@@@SFDC::Case Reason'+c.reason);
        if (!confs.isEmpty()) {
            conf = confs[0];
            System.debug('got template: ' + conf.Template_Name__c);
        }

        // get default template 
        if (conf==null) {
            confs = [SELECT Template_Name__c FROM Smart_Template_Loader_Conf__c WHERE Case_Status__c = '' AND Case_Reason__c = ''];
            if (!confs.isEmpty()) {
                conf = confs[0];
                System.debug('got template: ' + conf.Template_Name__c);
            }
        }

        if (conf==null) {
            System.debug('no template!');
            return null;
        }

        // get the template ID
        System.debug('@@@SFDC:'+conf.Template_Name__c);

        //List<EmailTemplate> ets = [SELECT id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = :conf.Template_Name__c];

        List<EmailTemplate> ets = [SELECT id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name = :conf.Template_Name__c ];

        System.debug('@@@SFDC'+ets);

        //Return the ID of the template selected
        if (!ets.isEmpty()) {
            EmailTemplate et = ets[0];
            System.debug('template: ' + conf.Template_Name__c + ' -- id: ' + et.id);
            return et.id;
        }
        System.debug('No template with the name: ' + conf.Template_Name__c);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just fetch recordType from existing case and by doing comparison you can assign template.

```
global ID getDefaultEmailTemplateId(ID caseId) {
    // Select the case we're interested in, choosing any fields that are relevant to our decision
    Case c = [SELECT Subject, Description, Recordtype.Name FROM Case WHERE Id=:caseId];

    EmailTemplate et;

    if (c.RecordType.Name.contains('Support Case')) {
        et = [SELECT id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = 'SupportTemplate'];
    } else if(c.RecordType.Name.contains('Enhancement')) {
        et = [SELECT id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = 'EnhancementTemplate'];
    } 

    // Return the ID of the template selected
    return et.id;
}
```

Comment: `misprision` ? = `The deliberate concealment of one’s knowledge of a treasonable act or a felony.`  per the dictionary. I've never seen this term used in computer science, thanks!

Comment: I don't think that I've heard of 'misprision' before. That's incredible.

Comment: It was TYPO. I have corrected it.

Comment: I only need to pull in the template into the Case Feed, not the ID. Unless I'm not understanding correctly, which is a definite probability.

So, if (c.RecordType.Name.contains('Geotab')) {, then it should be assigning the email template Default Email (Geotab_Email) when replying from the Case Feed emailing option.